# Scala -> Java , Pass function as a parameter to another function

Tags: java, scala

I am exploring both scala and Java 1.8 but unable to find equivalent code in with java 1.8 lambda expressions.

Scala code:

```
object Ex1 extends App {

  def single(x:Int):Int =x
  def square(x:Int):Int = x * x
  def cube(x:Int):Int = x*x*x

  def sum(f:Int=>Int,a:Int,b:Int):Int=if (a>b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f,a+1,b)

  def sumOfIntegers(a:Int,b:Int)=sum(single,a,b)
  def sumOfSquares(a:Int,b:Int)=sum(square,a,b);
  def sumOfCubes(a:Int,b:Int)=sum(cube,a,b);

  println(sumOfIntegers(1,4));
  println(sumOfSquares(1,4));
  println(sumOfCubes(1,4));

}

output:

10
30
100
```

---

java:

```
public class Test1{
    public int single(int x){
        return x;
    }
    public int square(int x){
        return x * x;
    }
    public int cube(int x){
        return x * x * x;
    }
    // what's next? How to implement sum() method as shown in Scala?
    // Stuck in definition of this method, Stirng s should be function type.
    public int sum( Sring s , int a, int b){
        // what will go here?
    }
    public int sumOfIntegers(int a, int b){
        return sum("single<Function> how to pass?",a,b);
    }
    public int sumOfSquares(int a, int b){
        return sum("square<Function> how to pass?",a,b);
    }
    public int sumOfCubes(int a, int b){
        return sum("cube<Function> how to pass?",a.b);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with JDK 1.8?

Comment: You should use the [IntUnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to define the methods that you are going to use. The only one that comes with Java is the `Function<X,Y>` which (with `Integer`) can be used for `single`, `square` and `cube` and `BiFunction<T,Y, R>` which can be used for the three `sumOf`s.

```
interface Sum {
    Integer apply(Function<Integer, Integer> func, int start, int end);
}
```

The single, square and cube could be either methods in the class (see `cube` or inline (see the other two). They are `Fuction`s. This function can then be passed to other methods and called with `variableName.apply`.

```
  class Test
{
    private static Integer sum(Function<Integer, Integer> func, int a, int b) {
        if (a>b)
            return 0;
        else return func.apply(a) + sum(func,a+1,b);
    }

    private static Integer cube(Integer a) {
        return a * a * a;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        Function<Integer,Integer> single = a -> a;
        Function<Integer,Integer> square = a -> a * a;
        Function<Integer,Integer> cube = Test::cube;

        // You can not do the sum in-line without pain due to its recursive nature.
        Sum sum = Test::sum;

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sumOfIntegers = (a, b) -> sum.apply(single, a, b);
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sumOfSquares = (a, b) -> sum(square, a, b); // You could just use the static method directly. 
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sumOfCubes = (a, b) -> sum(cube, a, b);

        System.out.println(sumOfIntegers.apply(1,4));
        System.out.println(sumOfSquares.apply(1,4));
        System.out.println(sumOfCubes.apply(1,4));
    }


}
```

Comment: Note: The `Function<Integer, Integer>` could be replaced with `IntUnaryOperator` if you wished.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
 public Integer sumSingle(Integer a) { return a; }

 public int sum(Function<Integer, Integer> f, int a, int b)
 {
      ... : f.apply(a+1); // or whatever
 }

 public int sumOfIntegers(int a, int b)
 {
     return sum(Test1::single, a, b);
 }
```

The construct `Class::method` creates a Function object from the method. Or if you don't need to reuse it, you can directly pass an argument instead: `(Integer a) -> a*a* ...`

Comment: If there are three parameters in single or square, function how does it look like? What I mean is separation of input value and output value. How to know?

Comment: Java 8 also support `BiFunction<A1, A2, R>` where A1 and A2 are argument types and R is the return type. There is AFAIK nothing for three/four/... parameters functions but you can either check third party libraries like functional java or create your own following the [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) pattern:

Answer (score 1):

```
Function<Integer, Integer> single = x -> x;
Function<Integer, Integer> square = x -> x*x;

public int sum( Function<Integer, Integer> s , int a, int b){
    if (a>b){
        return 0;
    } else {
        s.apply(a) + sum(s,a+1,b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Function gets Integer and returns Integer, as is written in <>. Right part is lambda expression, x - variable of Integer type after -> what we return. Function is an interface that has only one method apply()

Comment: If there are three parameters in single or square, function how does it look like? What I mean is separation of input value and output value. How to know?

Comment: The last type is return type.

Comment: But Function can have only 1 argument

Comment: You can write own interface with any arguments and use any of type as return type

Comment: If you want multiple parameters you can always use this: `Function<Integer[],Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use any [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), i.e. an interface with exactly one non-static method without a default implementation, in place of Scala's `Function<N>` types. There are quite a few such interfaces in the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package, for single-argument and two-argument functions; in particular for functions which take and return `int` you should use [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html), already mentioned in other people's comments. If you have more than two arguments, or two arguments of different types, define your own interface with one method. E.g. for functions of 3 arguments which take `int`, `long` and `long` and return a non-primitive:

```
interface Fun3ILLO<T> {
    public T apply(int arg1, long arg2, long arg3);
}
```

(obviously you can choose the interface and method name you want).